# Same value of two inputs angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can one input be the same value as another input via angularjs? I know how to do this via jquery but not in angularjs. Here is my code:

```
<body ng-app="peopleApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input class="form-control input-form" ng-model="input.user_code" name="user_code" type="text" maxlength="4" minlength="4"  required>
        <input class="form-control input-form" ng-model="input.username" name="username" type="text" required>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var peopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', []);
    peopleApp.controller('myController', function(){
        $scope.input = {
            'username': $scope.input.user_code
        }
    });
</script>
```

So basically what I want is the first input element to be the same value as the second input element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `ng-blur` or `ng-change`

```
<body ng-app="peopleApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input class="form-control input-form" ng-blur="input.username = input.user_code" ng-model="input.user_code" name="user_code" type="text" maxlength="4" minlength="4"   required>
        <input class="form-control input-form"  ng-model="input.username" name="username" type="text" required>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer above works, but if you want it to update in real time, just use the same model:

```
<input class="form-control input-form" ng-model="input.user_code" name="user_code" type="text" maxlength="4" minlength="4"  required>
<input class="form-control input-form" ng-model="input.user_code" name="username" type="text" required>
```

When you change one of the two, the other will update as well. You can also use this as any other tag. For example, this will show what you type on the <p> tag:

```
<input class="form-control input-form" ng-model="input.user_code" name="user_code" type="text" maxlength="4" minlength="4"  required>
<p> {{ input.user_code }} </p>
```